# Can CMake create soft-link to resource directory?

Tags: cmake, resources

Currently I copy resources (namely shaders) from source-code directory to Build directory using this command

```
file( COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
```

but I don't like that since I have to run `cmake` each time I did some change in resources, which makes for example debugging of GLSL shaders very tedious

I would prefer if cmake creates soft-link from resource directory to build directory, so that all changes in resources would be up-to-date without running `cmake` neither `make`. I would prefer If this can be done using as old version of cmake as possible.

---

**EDIT:**

the question is solved in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765106/symbolic-links-cmake). Just to make it clear I used like this:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( shaders ALL  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders )
```

Comment: maybe ... I just don't see how exactly should I use it  for my puprpose ... I will edit my question

Comment: it's the closest you can get it seems with `add_custom_target` like shown in the answer.