# CMake: Symlink files instead of copying them during install

Tags: cmake, symlink

Making CMake copy files during `make install` is simple:

```
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION lib)
install(DIRECTORY Include/ DESTINATION include)
```

But is it possible to write `make symlink` that will make symlinks instead of copying files? If so, how?

Comment: On Unix-like systems symlinks can be created with `cmake -E create_symlink` invocation ([command-line tool mode of CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode)). To perform actions on `make install` stage, use *SCRIPT* mode of `install` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you write to whole code into an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbolic links CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765106/symbolic-links-cmake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after reading the suggested answer and making a few attempts, I managed to write the code:

```
add_custom_target(symlink
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/libfoo.a ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libfoo.a
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Include ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
```

Answer (score 2):

Write CMake script which creates required symlink:

**symlink_include_dir.cmake.in**:

```
execute_process(COMMAND cmake -E create_symlink
    "@CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@/include" # Old name
    "@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/include" # New name
)
```

In `CMakeLists.txt` configure this script for adjust it for actual source and install paths, and call it from `install(SCRIPT)`:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# This will copy original script with @variable@ replaced with variable's value.
configure_file("symlink_include_dir.cmake.in" "symlink_include_dir.cmake"
   @ONLY)

# Tell CMake to use the script at install stage
install(SCRIPT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/symlink_include_dir.cmake")
```

Comment: So it runs during `make install`? Does it also symlink a library? Can you make it run during `make symlink` - a custom target?

Comment: Yes, it runs during `make install`. The script creates only those symlinks, which are given to `create_symlink`, if you want to create symlink for a library, you need to specify additional *COMMAND* for it. For run single (or several) *COMMAND* during build stage, use standard `add_custom_target`/`add_custom_command` approach. For run whole script at build stage, specify `COMMAND -P <path-to-script>`.

Comment: Can you write the whole code? I don't have knowledge to do it myself

Comment: You may take a code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35765320/3440745).

Comment: I have seen that answer but it doesn't come with the full code.

Comment: Its code is full for make a target `link_target` which creates symlink for `${target}` file (paste your path instead of this expression) named `${link}` (again, paste your path instead of this expression).

Comment: Very-very ugly.. As CMake itself.